# grails action required parameter check

Tags: grails

How can I check in Grails controller-action that all the required parameters has been provided  to this action method. In other words, can I simply specify using a map or list object for all the parameters which are required for my action.

I can get the params and do an explicit check in each action but that is lot of code just for simple validation. Is there a simple way so that a default error message is returned with the missing parameter name.

EDIT

There are two things I think I forgot to mention - 
1. These controller-action are for implementing webservices and they are not linked to a GSP. 2. The required params need vary greatly from action to action. Keeping that in mind using command object does not seem correct method. every method is going to have different required param and we can not create command object for each web service.

Spring has something similar where we can specify for each action, which are the params and whether they are required or optional.

Comment: If the solution of @tedias is too 'tedious', no pun intended, you could use JAX-RS directly right, that is, if you require great flexibility. You could also try grails-jaxrs -> https://github.com/krasserm/grails-jaxrs/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the data from params to populate an instance of a Domain class you can just set the constraints accordingly, populate an instance of the domain class,  and use the [validate](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html) method.

If the data you want to validate is not really related to a Domain class, you can still use about the same validation mechanism, by creating a [Command Object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) and specifying it in your controller action.

This is the Command Object example from the docs:

```
@grails.validation.Validateable
class LoginCommand {
    String username
    String password
    static constraints = {
        username(blank: false, minSize: 6)
        password(blank: false, minSize: 6)
    }
}
```

And then in the controller:

```
class LoginController {
    def login(LoginCommand cmd) {
        if (cmd.hasErrors()) {
            redirect(action: 'loginForm')
            return
        }
        // work with the command object data
    }
}
```

Relevant quote from [the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects):

> Before the controller action is executed Grails will automatically
>   create an instance of the command object class and populate its
>   properties by binding the request parameters. If the command object
>   class is marked with Validateable then the command object will be
>   validated.

Comment: Thanks Elias. Please check further modification provided me in the question.

Comment: You're welcome! I see, you're saying that there are too much different combinations of required parameters for you to create the generic command objects, correct? If it's indeed that case, it can be a good idea to try rolling your own validation mechanism. Maybe a method like `validateParams(params, [list, of, constraints])` -- you would have to come up with a good representation for the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

`Command` Objects are handy in those scenarios. You can define a command object with the `params` bindings and add constraints on each/all of them. You can also use custom `validator` to validate the request parameters (`params`).

for example:

```
//Command Object
class LoginCommand{
   String userName
   String password

   static constraints = {
        //Constraints and validator defined here 
   }
}
```

Accessing command object in Controller:

```
def myAction(LoginCommand lc){
   if(lc.hasErrors()){//redirect to error page or do something else}
}
```

You can find more details [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects).

Putting request parameter validations in command objects has below pros:

1. Controller is only meant for HTTP routes to actions and not for validations. Hence, separation of concern.
2. Since members of the command object are dynamically bound to `params` during execution of `action`, they act as business objects/beans where you can handle domain (application business domain) related logic as well.

**UPDATE**

Here is a [sample code](http://pastebin.com/KEVHH2zg) how Command Object can be used for validations for all the `actions` in a `controller`.

Comment: There are two things I think I forgot to mention - 1. These controller-action are for implementing webservices and they are not linked to a GSP. 2. The required params need vary greatly from action to action. Keeping that in mind using command object does not seem correct method. every method is going to have different required param and we can not create command object for each web service. Spring has something similar where we can specify for each action, which are the params and whether they are required or optional.

Comment: UrlMapping.groovy also has capability of defining constraints per action. You can look at that as well. If I am not mistaken, Command object should also hold good for web services (ex: REST) since the binding to command object happens after the action is called.

Comment: What I wanted to convey was very simple and would have helped making controller look simpler :). First, you can use command objects for RESTful webservices as well. Second, Validation in Contoller clutters the `controller` a lot. Third, you can have a single Command object to handle all of your `controller` `actions`. Fourth, you have full access to `validator` in Command Objects which is abstracted from `controller`. Have a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/KEVHH2zg) sample code.